# How can i get HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); value outside request mapping method

Tags: spring-mvc

This work fine

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/emailfrom2")
    public String displayLogin3(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    String gsSessionID = (String) session.getAttribute("GSSessionID");

    System.out.println("Session ===>>>> " + gsSessionID);
    logger.debug("displayLogin3()");

    return "users/test1";
}
```

but i want like this.like a global value.

```
public class UserController  {
String gsSessionID = (String) session.getAttribute("GSSessionID");  
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/emailfrom2")
public String displayLogin3(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

            System.out.println("Session ===>>>> " + gsSessionID);
            logger.debug("displayLogin3()");
            return "users/test1";
        }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/users/emailfrom5")
    public String displayLogin5(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

     String sessionId = getSessionProperty(request, "GSSessionID");

        System.out.println("Session ===>>>> " + sessionId);
        logger.debug("displayLogin3()");

        return "users/test1";
    }
```

}

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/users/emailfrom6")
public String displayLogin5(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

 String sessionId = getSessionProperty(request, "GSSessionID");

    System.out.println("Session ===>>>> " + sessionId);
    logger.debug("displayLogin3()");

    return "users/test1";
}
```

i just want to write  String sessionId = getSessionProperty(request, "GSSessionID"); only one time in controller class not twice or thrice or more. 
Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: You cant do that, but could create a generic method in an AbstractController which receives the request and returns that value, so you could use in several controllers

Comment: please give me any example link

Comment: @cralfaro please give me any example link please

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
public class UserController extends AbstractController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/users/emailfrom2")
    public String displayLogin3(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        String sessionId = getSessionID(request)

        System.out.println("Session ===>>>> " + sessionId);
        logger.debug("displayLogin3()");

        return "users/test1";
    }
}


public abstract class AbstractController {
    public String getSessionID(HttpServletRequest request){
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        return (String) session.getAttribute("GSSessionID");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If as you said you can need different values from session you should modify this method:

public abstract class AbstractController {

```
    protected String gSSessionID;
    protected String gSPresentDate;


    @PreProcess
    public void loadSessionAttributes(@SessionAttribute(name="GSSessionID") String gSSessionID,
                                      @SessionAttribute(name="GSPresentDate") String gSPresentDate){
        this.gSSessionID = gSSessionID;
        this.gSPresentDate = gSPresentDate;
        //Some other session attributes
    }
}

public class UserController extends AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/emailfrom2")
    public String displayLogin3(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        System.out.println("Session ===>>>> " + gSSessionID);
        logger.debug("displayLogin3()");

        return "users/test1";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Himel with this solution you could add to the AbstractController all methods you need to use in several controllers

Comment: what if i have multiple session  * String gsPresentDate = (String) session.getAttribute("GSPresentDate");
  * String gsSessionID = (String) session.getAttribute("GSSessionID"); String
  * gsInternalCardID =(String) session.getAttribute("GSInternalCardID");
  * String gsLogInToDay = (String) session.getAttribute("GSLogInToDay");

Comment: if i have 100 method in my controller class then i have to convert into string  hundred times then pass in method parameter what is the solution ?

Comment: Use the example i added, with a new parameter you can scale to N different properties from the session

Comment: @cralfro String sessionId  need 100 times  in   RequestMapping .what should i do that was my point. i have to write String sessionId = getSessionProperty(request, "GSSessionID"); in every  RequestMapping.i want to write only one time in  like global value so that i can get it in every  RequestMapping method.is it possible?

Comment: @Himel I got what you mean, I think you could do a mix between; 1. create an abstract controller; 2. create a method with PreProcess annotation, then add as attributes all session values with SessionAttribute(name="XX") String sessionID; 4. set those values to protected properties and will be accessible for all controllers which extend the abstract

Comment: @cralfro i am new so if you give me demo code it will be helpful

Comment: @Himel check the Update section of my response